# state update not correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a problem with my form and it is that its state is not updated correctly, it is updated when writing one more character of the input, for example:

I have a function that validates that the user has numbers and letters:

> usuario: 123456789a ---> it does not work

> usuario: 123456789ab ---> it works

When I put that I get the validation wrong, but adding any more number or letter if it works (it is as if it had 1 delay character). I provide the code and screenshots of it

function **includeNumbers**

```
const letters = "abcdefghyjklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"

const includesLetters = (text) => {
  text = text.toLowerCase()
    for(let i=0; i<text.length; i++){
       if (letters.indexOf(text.charAt(i), 0) !== -1){
          return 1;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

export default includesLetters
```

function **includeLetters**

```
  const numbers = "0123456789"

   const includesNumbers = (text) => {
       for(let i=0; i<text.length; i++){
          if (numbers.indexOf(text.charAt(i), 0) !== -1){
             return 1;
          }
       }
       return 0;
   }

   export default includesNumbers
```

CODIGO donde declaro el reducer:

```
const ACTIONSOFERRORS = {
  UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR: "update_account_error",
  UPDATE_PASSWORD_ERROR: "update_password_error",
  UPDATE_COUNTRY_ERROR: "update_country_error",
  UPDATE_PHONE_ERROR: "update_phone_error",
  UPDATE_NAME_ERROR: "update_name_error",
  UPDATE_LASTNAME_ERROR: "update_lastname_error",
  UPDATE_EMAIL_ERROR: "update_email_error",
  UPDATE_CHECKBOX_ERROR: "update_checkbox_error",
  RESET_ERRORS: "reset_errors",
};

const initialStateErrors = {
  accountError: [false, ""],
  passwordError: [false, ""],
  countryError: [false, ""],
  phoneError: [false, ""],
  nameError: [false, ""],
  lastNameError: [false, ""],
  emailError: [false, ""],
  submit: [false],
};


const reducerErrors = (stateErrors, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        accountError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_PASSWORD_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        passwordError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_COUNTRY_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        countryError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_EMAIL_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        emailError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_LASTNAME_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        lastNameError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_PHONE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        phoneError: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_CHECKBOX_ERROR:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        check: action.payload,
      };

    case ACTIONSOFERRORS.RESET_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...stateErrors,
        stateErrors: initialStateErrors,
      };

    default:
      return stateErrors;
  }
};
const [stateErrors, dispatchErrors] = useReducer(
    reducerErrors,
    initialStateErrors
);
```

Code where I carry out the verifications:

```
   <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        label="Account"
        name="user"
        id="user"
        // value={account}
        // error={error}
        value={account}
        error={accountError[0]}
        helperText={accountError[1]}
        onChange={(evt) => {
          const { value } = evt.target;
          dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT,
            payload: value,
          });

          account.includes(" ")
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username not accept spacing"],
              })
            : account.length < 8
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username requerid more of 8 digits"],
              })
            : !(includesNumbers(account) && includesLetters(account))
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "User is required letters and numbers"],
              })
            : dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [false, ""],
              });
        }}
      />
```

IMAGE 1:
[image: IMAGE WITH ERROR]

IMAGE 2:
[image: IMAGE WITH NOT ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a delay of one character. Here's why:
`dispatch` from `useReducer` is asynchronous (just like the setter function from `useState`), so calling `dispatch()` will not immediately update the `account` object.

There are two routes you could go with:

### Use `value` instead of `account` in your onChange function

```
onChange={(evt) => {
          const { value } = evt.target;
          // this will only update the account variable eventually, not immediately
          dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT,
            payload: value,
          });

          value.includes(" ")
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username not accept spacing"],
              })
            : value.length < 8
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username requerid more of 8 digits"],
              })
            : !(includesNumbers(value) && includesLetters(value))
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "User is required letters and numbers"],
              })
            : dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [false, ""],
              });
        }}
```

### Better: Use the `useEffect` hook

```
 // in your component function:
 useEffect(()=>{
            account.includes(" ")
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username not accept spacing"],
              })
            : account.length < 8
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "Username requerid more of 8 digits"],
              })
            : !(includesNumbers(account) && includesLetters(account))
            ? dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [true, "User is required letters and numbers"],
              })
            : dispatchErrors({
                type: ACTIONSOFERRORS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT_ERROR,
                payload: [false, ""],
              });
}, [account]); // runs the validation whenever the account variable changes


 //... inside the return:
 // onChange function:
 onChange={(evt) => {
          const { value } = evt.target;
          dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT,
            payload: value,
          });
          // do nothing else
 }}
```

You could of course also modify your reducers by integrating the errors in the same reducer as the one containing the `account` variable and update the corresponding error when `ACTIONS.UPDATE_ACCOUNT` is called.

Comment: Another query, is it better to make an effect for each validation or put everything in the same effect?